# Menubar in _Layout.cshtml - Display elements depending on context logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This a MVC .DotNet Core project. In _Layout.cshtml , I would like to display menu elements depending on context logic. The user must selects at first a HouseGroup in a list to have the page House available.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>
            <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="About">About</a></li>
            <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Contact">Contact</a></li>
           <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="HouseGroups" asp-action="Index">HouseGroup</a></li>
            <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Houses" asp-action="Index">House</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

It means that initially, the menu HouseGroup is not visible and becomes visible when a House in the page House is selected. To keep in memory the active HouseGroup, I store the HouseGroupID in a NavigationContext object I registered in Startup.cs as a Singleton:

`services.AddSingleton<NavigationContext>();`

I don't see how I can properly obtain that the menu list in _Layout.cshtml depends on a business logic. How I could link this with a Controller without having trouble with the other Views which are rendered in by @RenderBody() such as House and HouseGroup views (Views/Houses/Index.cshtml, Views/Houses/Create.cshtml, Views/HouseGroups/Index.cshtml, Views/HouseGroups/Edit.cshtml, ...).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It means that initially, the menu **House** is not visible and becomes visible when a **HouseGroup** in the page **HouseGroup** is selected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented an authorization system based on this tutorial : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/secure-data?view=aspnetcore-2.1 . In any .cshtml page, we can add reference with @using and inject objects with @inject . Be careful to protect each action in the controller as well to avoid that the user perform actions by sending fake objects to the server.

For my case, I moved the main part of the NavigationContext to the Session layer according to this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1#session-state .